# python replace env params in a string which is not a path

Tags: python, regex

Patterns I can receive can vary and I have used

```
line1 = "$ABC/xyz"
line2 = "123_$ABC_xyz"
line3 = "abc_$XYZ_123_def_$ABC"
line4 = "$XYZ_def_abc"
exp = os.path.expandvars(line)
```

As I understand expandvars works on line1 and not line2 /line3
So I extracted the pattern with `regex --> r"\$([A-Z0-9_]*(?<!_))"`

```
result = re.search(r"(\$([A-Z0-9_]*(?<!_)))", line2)
print (result.group(2))
```

Problem : How do I pass the variable to `os.environ()`, as this doesn't seem to accept any variables only strings. I tried even `envsubst` which also is not working.

And for line3, there are more than one env param i want to replace. Is there any python package which will do the replacement which i can use or do I need to use a recursive call to a function I write?

Any inputs for this would be of great help.
Please do let me know if I need to provide any more details.

Expected Ouput:
os.environ['ABC'] = 'WSS'
os.environ['XYZ'] = 'OK'

```
line1 = "WSS/xyz"
line2 = "123_WSS_xyz"
line3 = "abc_OK_123_def_WSS"
line4 = "OK_def_abc"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access environmental variable values by name using `os.environ[env_var_name]`.

If you set an environment variable `ABC` with the value of `WSS`, this is what you may get with the following code:

```py
import os, re
print(os.environ['ABC']) # => WSS

lines = ['$ABC/xyz', '123_$ABC_xyz', 'abc_$XYZ_123_def_$ABC', 'sss_${ABC}']
rx = re.compile(r'\${([A-Za-z0-9_]+)}|\$([A-Za-z0-9]+)')
def repl(m):
    if m.group(1):
        return os.environ.get(m.group(1),m.group())
    elif m.group(2):
        return os.environ.get(m.group(2),m.group())
    else:
        return m.group()

for line in lines:
    print( rx.sub(repl, line) )
```

Output:

```
WSS/xyz
123_WSS_xyz
abc_$XYZ_123_def_WSS
sss_WSS
```

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor ..will try this.  will check lambda as well.. as i am quite new to python.

Comment: @pupil If it does not work, please feel free to drop a comment to clarify what you need.

Comment: I want the $ABC in all the strings to be replaced. I want the env params in all places in the line to be replaced. Sorry for the delay in my response as i was trying to better understand to make the change.

Comment: @pupil So, my answer works for you, as it does what you just wrote.

Comment: it didnt work for all cases. i have given expected output in the question just to clarify. even in your output ..there are few plaves where $ABC didnt get replaced with the value of WSS. case in point second output

Comment: @pupil That is because `\$([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(?<!_)` [works like this](https://regex101.com/r/w4AFMC/1). If you need to match a variable containing underscores, you should use the same convention as in Bash, i.e. `${ABC_DEF}`. If not, the regex you must use is `\$([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Comment: Thank you @wiktor, will try using the ${param} syntax then

Comment: @pupil Then use [`\${([A-Za-z0-9_]+)}|\$([A-Za-z0-9]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/w4AFMC/2) regex. I updated the solution.